# Is it possible to insert a 'row' into a view composed of multiple tables with a common auto-increment primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-structures

I've been reading up more about views in MySQL (not being my strongpoint), but I'm now wondering if anyone has an example of how to insert a row into a view composed of more than one table, where there is a supertype and subtype relationship?

For example, the 'party model' hierarchy, showing roles of employer and staff:

```
      party
    _ _ | _ _
   |         |
employer   staff
```

The tables for which (simplified):

```
party                             employer               staff
--------------------------------  ---------------------  -----------------
party_ID INT auto_increment (PK)  party_ID INT (FK)      party_ID INT (FK)
party_name VARCHAR                tax_reference VARHCAR  job_title VARCHAR
etc...                            etc...                 etc...
```

I know I can create a view to deal with just the relationship concerned:

```
CREATE VIEW staff_view AS SELECT party.party_ID, etc... FROM party INNER JOIN staff
```

When I add a member of staff, I want to create a record in the party table, then reference the auto-increment `party_ID` in the staff table. I can't see how to perform an insert in one statement, something like:

```
INSERT INTO staff_view (party_name, job_title, etc...) VALUES ('John Doe', 'CEO', etc)
```

I know I can acheive this programatically, but I am hoping there's a way to do it directly in the database and maintain the referential integrity. How would you approach this issue?

(MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html)

Comment: You can't insert into a multiple-table view unless you only specify fields from 1 source table.  The only way I can think of to do your insert with a single query would be to write a stored procedure.

Comment: @Sam, do you have an example of how you might you use stored procedures to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can solve your problem with a insert [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)?

Comment: Hi flob - do you have any pointers as to how this might be achieved? If the trigger for staff is defined before the insert statement for party, how can the values for staff be sent at the same time as those for party?

Comment: In the trigger you can do an insert into the party table and after that use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the value of your foreign key for the next insert. If you do that in one transaction, it will be 'at the same time' for other sessions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Hi, I've marked this question as the answer, as it's technically not possible to do as I ask directly, and so the trigger method is the best fit.

Comment: Also have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469656/fill-mysql-records-one-to-many-related-tables-in-one-action